# Can I safely ignore CodeAnalysis warning: replace string == "" with string.IsNullOrEmpty?

Tags: c#, code-analysis, isnullorempty

I've got code similar to this:

```
string s = CreateString();
if (s == "") foo(s);
```

If s equals "", foo should be called. If string is null, which should never happen, then a NullReferenceException is fine (as this is, after all, an exceptional situation).

CodeAnalysis tells me to test for s.IsNullOrEmpty. This would alter the functionality in a nunintended way.

Performance is not an issue.

Is it safe to suppress the associated CA1820 warning?

**Edit:** Updated code sample and text to better reflect my case.

**Edit:** This is the (slightly altered) actual code (it's in a standard IXmlSerializable implementation):

```
public void ReadXml (XmlReader reader)
    // ...
    string img = reader.ReadElementString ("Image");
    if (img != "") {
        Image = Image.FromFile(img);
    }
    // ...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will behave differently with regards to nulls, so it depends what you want to happen; you mention that `NullReferenceException` would be OK, but there is nothing in the code cited that would raise this, hence why it could cause unexpected errors downstream.

I never *have*, but I'm always tempted to add:

```
static bool IsNullOrEmpty(this string value) {
    return string.IsNullOrEmpty(value);
}
```

so I can use:

```
if (s.IsNullOrEmpty()) foo();
```

Comment: You're missing a "this" inside the parenthesis to make the method an extension ;)
Anyway I've used that for a long time now...it just reads much better.

Comment: I already added the missing "this" in an "oops I'm a muppet" edit ;-p

Comment: You Brits and your aphorisms.  Makes me want to move to the UK.

Answer (score 3):

Specs :

> If s equals "", foo should be called.
>   If string is null, which should never
>   happen, then a NullReferenceException
>   is fine.

Just [test the **string length** as adviced in the CodeAnalysis rule](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182279.aspx) :

```
if (s.Length == 0) foo(s);
```

**Your question :**

> Is it safe to suppress the associated
>   CA1820 warning?

You can ignore it, your code will work but I wouldn't advice it, **follow the guidelines** as much as you can. Even if the topic (performance) is not an issue, your code will be more consistent and you get accustomed to write standard code.

Answer (score 2):

Every Code Analysis warning has associated documentation that you can access by highligting the warning and pressing **F1**. You can also right-click on the item to get help.

In any case, here's the [documentation that explains that particular warning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182279.aspx).

According to that documentation, it is "safe to suppress a warning from this rule if performance is not an issue".

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to write the test as:

```
if(s != null && s == "")
```

You can then process a null value in another if statement

Comment: Adding an extra test for null actually makes sense and removes the warning. A simple yet good idea.

Answer (score 1):

You're not really ignoring the warning, you've looked at the code and decided that the warning doesn't apply.  This is a perfectly reasonable condition under which to suppress the warning.

**Pure Speculation**

I wish I knew a little more about what you were trying to do, however.  I suspect that there may be a better way to handle it.  The pattern reminds me of returning an error message or empty to signal the success of a method.  If that's the case, I would consider either returning void and throwing an exception on failure or returning bool and only throwing exceptions when the message is critical and returning true/false otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

If null is OK, you'll be fine either way.

Answer (score 0):

yes.

But i would agree with CodeAnalysis with string.IsnullOrEmpty is a safe choice.

Answer (score 0):

Not handling exception whereas you Can is gennerally a bad idea so CA is right in that you either need to treat null as empty or handle the exception. A null reference exception caused by using a return value is a very bad thing. At the very least put in a Debug.Assert(s!=null) and compare to string.Empty

Comment: My understanding of the question is that the method never returns null.  In that case it really would be an exceptional condition and ok to throw the exception.  Yes, it's a bad thing but based on his code it should never happen.